# Rails routing exception => unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do

Tags: syntax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Ruby v = 1.9.3
Rails v = 3.1.0

I'm still learning rails - anyone know why the heck this would happen?

Routing file - match "/go_to/work" => "go_to#work"

Boot server - exception => syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expection keyword_do or '{} or '('

It's pointing to the first character after the string 'match "', so the first '/'.

I have another test app I created the exact same way, but this doesn't happen. The controller/action and view are set up correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Go ahead an answer your own question and accept it. It will help others searching for a solution (even if it was a typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, I'm an idiot. I had mistakenly changed my routing file definition at the top of the page to -> Double::Application.routes.draw doation: